# Cordova Android app ignoring config.xml and AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, cordova

My Android Cordova app is experiencing odd behaviour and apparently ignoring directives set in config.xml and AndroidManifest.xml. Specifically, external hyperlinks in text appear to be completely inactive, writing to the external storage isn't working and my geolocation button throws up the following error in Android Studio's debugger:

```
Caught security exception while registering for location updates from the system. 
The application does not have sufficient geolocation permissions.
```

I have read many Q&As on these issues, all point to the two XML files mentioned above.

My config.xml includes:

```
<access launch-external="yes" origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
```

and my AndroidManifest.xml includes:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

My index.html includes:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; media-src *">
```

(which seems to be working, as changing this prevents the app loading some external JS libraries over the internet)

...which seems to cover everyone's advice on the subject that I can find. It's like the XML files are being ignored.

The app compiles and runs on iOS just fine, by the way.

Comment: you mean to say AndroidManifest.xml settings are not considered?

Comment: It would appear that way, yes, as well as settings defined in config.xml also being ignored/not considered.

Comment: Could you give some specific info like  what you set and got ignored.. also error trace if any...